# sql select and group by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to select and group by date from MySQL.

table looks like this:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `run_data` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_day` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `number_of_links` int(20) NOT NULL,
```

for selecting, I'm using:

```
SELECT date_day, SUM(number_of_links) FROM my_table GROUP BY date_day DESC LIMIT 30
```

I'm getting total number of links per day but I can not sort it by date. date_day from my database is just:

```
$date_day = date('d/m/Y', time());
```

any ideas how to fix that ?

what I tried so far:

```
GROUP BY TO_DAYS(`run_data`)
GROUP BY MONTH(run_data)
GROUP BY DATE(STR_TO_DATE(run_data));
```

Comment: Maybe silly question but why do not you keep your date in proper DATE column format? eg DATE

Comment: Right now you are complicating so simple thing

Comment: Can you show some sample row of data saved inside table

Comment: you need to cast the date string back to a date, then sort by the date you calculated - Years of experience have shown, that whatever it is that frightens people about the SQL 'date' and 'datetime' data type - it is all much less than the problems of storing a date as a string, and d/m/y and m/d/y are much more problematic than yyyy/mm/dd - which gives you a fighting chance actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `date_day` field is not sortable. At least not unless you write custom logic for it, which is usually done in PHP; Or doing casting it on each query, which can be very expensive for the database (not to mention give incorrect results).

As mentioned in the comment by @nospor, the correct answer to this question is to alter the field to be a proper `date` field. Then you can easily sort and/or group it.
To accomplish this I recommend looking up on the `ALTER TABLE` syntax in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: thanks, what about `run_data` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ? can I use that ?

Comment: That depends upon whether or not it contains the same data as the `date_day` field. As I don't know the answer to that, I cannot say for certain. Though, if they contain the same data, why have two fields for it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you date_day is stored like a  string in format  'd/m/Y' you shold convert the string in date

```
SELECT date_day, SUM(number_of_links) 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY date_day 
ORDER BY str_to_date(date_day, '%d/%m/%Y') DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: There is written in what format he has a string... Please do not assume sth which is already given.

Comment: @nospor   .. the column in table is a  varchar  and in my answer at the begin there is an alert for the format

Comment: He said exactly in what format he has that date... It is 'd/m/Y' not as you assumed dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: @nospor  .. character separator updated .. and   php d/m/Y is equivalent of mysql %d/%m%Y

Comment: Still you did not update your assumption in description ;)

Comment: Thank you :) And yes, I know that "php d/m/Y is equivalent of mysql %d/%m%Y"

Answer (score 0):

Your `date_day` is of `varchar` type, so to sort your result on `date_day` you have to cast it into `date` datatype, like this:

```
SELECT date_day, SUM(number_of_links)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY date_day
ORDER BY CAST(date_day AS DATE()) DESC
LIMIT 30
```